# MongoError: Cannot apply $addToSet to non-array field. Field named 'trackTime' has non-array type string

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Here i'm trying to update with the `userid, trackTime` fields. Evertime userid and trackTime will be different so i'm using `$addToSet`but here i'm facing an error

like this i'm passing the data in postman:-

```
{
 "courseId":"61001184afeacb22ac1668e0",
 "userId":"60f6fe96a1a44a1fb4a59573",
 "trackingTime":"4"
}
```

this is the schema:-

```
 usersEnrolled : [{
    iscourseenrolled : { type:Boolean, default: false },
    userId: {type: String },
    trackTime: {type:String}
 }],
```

code:-

```
const updatedTrackTime = await Courses.updateOne({ "_id" : req.body.courseId},{
  $addToSet:{
    "usersEnrolled.0.userId" : req.body.userId,
    "usersEnrolled.0.trackTime": req.body.trackingTime 
 }})
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just changed in to these and it worked for me

```
const updatedTrackTime = await Courses.updateOne({ "_id" : req.body.courseId},{ $addToSet:{
usersEnrolled : {
   userId : req.body.userId,
   trackTime: req.body.trackingTime
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that error is probably because you didn't specify the array field (Actually you didn't specify any field at all). Try to add your `usersEnrolled` field like this:

```
const updatedTrackTime = await Courses.updateOne({ "_id" : req.body.courseId},{
  $addToSet:{
    usersEnrolled: {
      "usersEnrolled.0.userId" : req.body.userId,
      "usersEnrolled.0.trackTime": req.body.trackingTime
    }
 }});
```

To get more details on `$addToSet` use MongoDB Manual
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/

Comment: userid, trackTime is not updating in the database